# Generating a HTML report of a coverage file using Jacoco?

Tags: android, html, jacoco, test-coverage

I am trying to generate a code coverage report in HTML from Jacoco.

After executing the following, I received a FileNotFoundException.

I saved the jacoco.jar directly into "C:\Jacoco" and ran the command.

```
Command: java -jar jacococli.jar report --classfiles C:\Users\tavis\AndroidStudioProjects\traccar-client-android\app\src\main\java C:\Users\tavis\AndroidStudioProjects\traccar-client-android\app\build\outputs\coverage\coverage.exec file --html html/report/location --name Traccar_Client_CC

Error: 

[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\Users\tavis\AndroidStudioProjects\traccar-client-android\app\build\outputs\coverage\coverage.exec.
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\Jacoco\file.
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.tools.ExecFileLoader.load(ExecFileLoader.java:72)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.commands.Report.loadExecutionData(Report.java:99)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.commands.Report.execute(Report.java:83)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.execute(Main.java:90)
        at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.main(Main.java:105)
```